# Fragment to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to pass the fragment to fragment but if i pass the new fragment i show old fragment widgets why?

[image]

this code is in MessageFragment
I want to go from MessageFragment to HomeFragment but i can but i show message fragment edittext, imageview etc. why?

```
 public void goMessagesToHome(){
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentMessage, homeFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Why you're replacing same fragment(homeFragment). Transact what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

ı have to do that i have navhostfragment so i write that.

```
  public void goMessagesToHome(){
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navHostFragment, homeFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navHostFragment, homeFragment);

this place is important